# Do angular expressions have a max length?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, expression, submit

I have solved this problem, but it left me scratching my head and I'm wondering if any of you `Angular` geniuses can shed some light as to why this fixed the problem.

I had a `basic form` with a `submit binding` that looked like this:

```
<form name="changePasswordForm" ng-submit="vm.changePassword(changePasswordForm)">
    //basic change password inputs
</form>
```

Every time the `form submitted` I kept getting this `error`:

```
fn is not a function
```

After `changing` my `ng-submit` binding to look like this

```
ng-submit="vm.cp(changePasswordForm)"
```

Everything works!?

I've went back and set it back up the way that I originally had it, and got the same error again. It seems like `Angular Expressions` get `truncated` after so many characters. Can anyone confirm or deny this?

Comment: not unusual to see expressions longer than yours. Create demo that replicates this problem

Comment: I feel like you've got some uglify issues hitting your code

Comment: @Parris This is still in development and is not minified.

Comment: @charlie I'll see if I can wire up a plunker showing the same issue.

Comment: I didn't really mean uglify in specific.  Do you have any sort if a build that might be modifying your code?

Comment: not at this time I do not.

Answer (score 1):

Could it have been the form name conflict issue described here.  https://calendee.com/2014/08/30/angularjs-form-names-conflict-with-scope-methods/

Comment: Try to provide more explanation to your answers. If that link dies, it becomes useless to future SO users. See [How to answer page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for help in improving your answer.

Comment: I like this, but the name of the form was `changePasswordForm` and the name of the method was `vm.changePassword`.